# Updating multi level embedded mongo array

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm having trouble finding the right syntax to replace an array of objects nested several levels deep within a collection. My preference is to just update the individual properties, but since reading the link below, it seems replacing the whole array is the best bet.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

So I have the following classes as an example:

```
public class Parent
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public Collection<Child> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public Collection<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pet
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Using the following code I create a Parent, add some Children, and add a Pet to one of the children.

```
// Construct Objects
Parent parent = new Parent() { _id = new ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecb1") };

Collection<Child> children = new Collection<Child>();
Collection<Pet> pets = new Collection<Pet>();

children.Add(new Child() 
    { _id = new ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecaf"), 
      Firstname = "Child", 
      Lastname = "One" });
children.Add(new Child() 
    { _id = new ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecb0"), 
      Firstname = "Child", 
      Lastname = "Two" });
pets.Add(new Pet() { Name = "Fishy" });

parent.Children = children;
parent.Children[0].Pets = pets;

// Connect to Mongo
var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost/?safe=true");
var db = server.GetDatabase("test");

// Insert into parent collection
MongoCollection<Parent> parents;
parents = db.GetCollection<Parent>("parents");
parents.Insert<Parent>(parent, MongoDB.Driver.SafeMode.True);
```

This successfully inserts the objects, generating the following JSON result:

```
{   "_id" : ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecb1"),
    "Firstname" : null,
    "Lastname" : null,
    "Children" : 
    [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecaf"),
            "Firstname" : "Child",
            "Lastname" : "One",
            "Pets" : 
            [
                {
                    "Name" : "Fishy"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecb0"),
            "Firstname" : "Child",
            "Lastname" : "Two",
            "Pets" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

Updating individual document elements also seems to be a trivial process, and works successfully with the following code.

```
// Change children's name
var query = new QueryDocument { { "Children._id", new ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecaf") } };
var update = Update.Set("Children.$.Firstname", "Something");
parents.Update(query, update);
```

Now the issue I can't work out is how to replace the Pets array. The following code doesn't compile as Update.Set doesn't accept a Collection.

```
// Change pets information
pets[0].Name = "Fishy2"; // change to pet
pets.Add(new Pet() { Name = "Doggy" }); // add new pet

query = new QueryDocument { { "Children._id", new ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecaf") } };
update = Update.Set("Children.$.Pets", pets);
parents.Update(query, update);
```

So what's the best process that would enable me to update the details in the Pets array?

Comment: Why on earth are you using a bloody array to do this.  It would be fair easier with a Generic Collection!

Comment: @Ramhound: he is using a generic collection.  To what are you referring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code you are looking for:  You'll need to pass in a BsonArray to the Update.Set value.  To create that array, you'll need to wrap each of the "pets" in a BsonDocumentWrapper so the serialization library knows how to serialize them appropriately.

```
var query = new QueryDocument { { "Children._id", new ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecaf") } };
var petDocuments = BsonDocumentWrapper.CreateMultiple(pets);
var petArray = new BsonArray(petDocuments);
var update = Update.Set("Children.$.Pets", petArray);
parents.Update(query, update);
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Craig. Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

```
> db.Questions.find().pretty()
{
        "Answers" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("52ae4946e1df9e1b10e1f6e1"),
                        "Text" : "ans",
                        "Comments" : [ ]
                }
        ],
        "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2013-12-16T00:28:47.790Z"),
        "QuestionText" : "test",
        "QuestionTitle" : "test",
        "Tag" : "test",
        "UserID" : "singleuserid_777",
        "_id" : ObjectId("52ae493fe1df9e1b10e1f6e0")
}
>
```

Now if I need to update Comments array in Answers array in Questions collection then my C#.Net code will be

```
  base.GetContext.Collection.Find(Query.EQ("Answers._id", ObjectId.Parse(Id))).Collection.Update(Query.EQ("Answers._id", ObjectId.Parse(Id)),MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.PushWrapped("Answers.$.Comments", comm));
```